# Legacy code does not work with new large csv file

Tags: pandas, large-files

I have legacy code writing for pandas.

Now the new data become very large (in CSV format), and it is hard to read_csv with the new files (the file sizes ~ 7,8GB and will be larger in the future).

Could you suggest me the best way to not change the legacy code but still working with large CSV files? I thought to switch to spark but it seems that I will have to change a lot of code.

Many thanks

Comment: Your best bet is to chunk it, `read_csv` provide it by `chunksize`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the file in chunks? And defining the column dtypes beforehand might help boost the performance

```py
chunksize = 1000000
chunks = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype=dtypes, chunksize=chunksize)
df = pd.concat((chunk for chunk in chunks), ignore_index=True)
```

**EDIT**: Another trick is to reduce the dataframe's memory usage after loading. This is from a [Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/arjanso/reducing-dataframe-memory-size-by-65)

```py
def reduce_mem_usage(props):
    start_mem_usg = props.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2 
    print("Memory usage of properties dataframe is :",start_mem_usg," MB")
    NAlist = [] # Keeps track of columns that have missing values filled in. 
    for col in props.columns:
        if props[col].dtype != object:  # Exclude strings

            # Print current column type
            print("******************************")
            print("Column: ",col)
            print("dtype before: ",props[col].dtype)

            # make variables for Int, max and min
            IsInt = False
            mx = props[col].max()
            mn = props[col].min()

            # Integer does not support NA, therefore, NA needs to be filled
            if not np.isfinite(props[col]).all(): 
                NAlist.append(col)
                props[col].fillna(mn-1,inplace=True)  

            # test if column can be converted to an integer
            asint = props[col].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
            result = (props[col] - asint)
            result = result.sum()
            if result > -0.01 and result < 0.01:
                IsInt = True


            # Make Integer/unsigned Integer datatypes
            if IsInt:
                if mn >= 0:
                    if mx < 255:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.uint8)
                    elif mx < 65535:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.uint16)
                    elif mx < 4294967295:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.uint32)
                    else:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.uint64)
                else:
                    if mn > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and mx < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.int8)
                    elif mn > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and mx < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.int16)
                    elif mn > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and mx < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.int32)
                    elif mn > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and mx < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                        props[col] = props[col].astype(np.int64)    

            # Make float datatypes 32 bit
            else:
                props[col] = props[col].astype(np.float32)

            # Print new column type
            print("dtype after: ",props[col].dtype)
            print("******************************")

    # Print final result
    print("___MEMORY USAGE AFTER COMPLETION:___")
    mem_usg = props.memory_usage().sum() / 1024**2 
    print("Memory usage is: ",mem_usg," MB")
    print("This is ",100*mem_usg/start_mem_usg,"% of the initial size")
    return props, NAlist
```

You can simply apply the above function to your dataframe, and it will help especially in cases where your data has many numeric columns.

Comment: Many thanks, but I have the problem not only with reading the file but also processing the data afterwards.

Comment: See my updated comment. If that doesn't help either, then I think it's time to switch to something like data.table, dask or Modin (before considering Spark)

Comment: And don't forget to use vectorised operations as much as possible if you want to stick with pandas.